# From html table to input on cell click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a pricetable with many cells, if I click on cell im getting data like "Item Name, Item Quantity and Item Format" in alert with:

```
$(function() {
  $('#table').on('click', 'td', function(e) {
      var format = e.delegateTarget.tHead.rows[0].cells[this.cellIndex],
          quantity  = this.parentNode.cells[0],
          name = document.querySelectorAll("#item_name");

          alert([$(name).text(), $(quantity).text(), $(format).text()]);
  })
});
```

Now the question, I want to pass this data to my contact form into disabled inputfield. But i dont realy know how to. I hope you can understand what I mean!
Url to table is  : mydoamin.com/catalog/item/1
Url to contact is: mydomain.com/contact

Code for my input field:

```
<div class="form-group">
<label for="subject" class="control-label">Bestellung</label>
<?php print form_error('order'); ?>
<?php print form_input('order', set_value('order'), 'placeholder="" class="form-control" id="disabledInput" disabled'); ?>
</div>
```

Fiddle with table and JS code:
https://jsfiddle.net/0bof336t/1/

Thank you!

Comment: how does your "my contact form into disabled inputfield" look like?

Comment: Can you share entire code or fiddle ? I think there is a lots of scope of improvement in your code..

Comment: Can you show the HTML for your form please.

Comment: Added my code for input field im my question. Thank you!

Comment: If you already use jQuery, then use it... You are overcomplicating thing with your plain js transversal logic

Comment: Hay @A. Wolff this is my problem I dont realy know JS and im trying to learn it and this is my task right now, but I cant understand how to post data that im getting from cell click into inputfield.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$('#disabledInput').val(<value to insert>);` to insert value to input. In your case something like this: `$('#disabledInput').val($(name).text());`

```
$(function() {
      $('#table').on('click', 'td', function(e) {
          var format = e.delegateTarget.tHead.rows[0].cells[this.cellIndex],
              quantity  = this.parentNode.cells[0],
              name = document.querySelectorAll("#item_name");
                $('#disabledInput').val($(name).text());
              alert([$(name).text(), $(quantity).text(), $(format).text()]);
      })
    });
```

If your input is in another page, then you should pass value by get method or by cookie.

**By GET method**

Javacript

```
$(function() {
      $('#table').on('click', 'td', function(e) {
          var format = e.delegateTarget.tHead.rows[0].cells[this.cellIndex],
              quantity  = this.parentNode.cells[0],
              name = document.querySelectorAll("#item_name");
                window.location.replace('url/?value='+$(name).text());
      })
    });
```

And then in your php file should be something like this:
`<?php print form_input('order', $_GET['value'], 'placeholder="" class="form-control" id="disabledInput" disabled'); ?>`

**By COOKIE method**

Javascript

```
$(function() {
          $('#table').on('click', 'td', function(e) {
              var format = e.delegateTarget.tHead.rows[0].cells[this.cellIndex],
                  quantity  = this.parentNode.cells[0],
                  name = document.querySelectorAll("#item_name");
                  document.cookie = inputValue + "=" + $(name).text()+ "; " + 3600000 +"; path=/";
          })
        });
```

And then you can access cookies with php and select value from it.

Comment: Thank you. I forgot to tell that table and contact are on other pages. I edited my question already.. Im not sure, I think about ajax, but im not sure about it... and if yes how to..

Comment: I have updated my answer. Ajax is not what are you looking for, you have to redirect to page after cell click with value in GET parameter or you can save your value in COOKIE if you redirect user to form page later

Comment: Thank you!! You saved my day!